# displaying Text if a statement isnt true

Tags: php

How would i wrap this in an IF statement so it displayed a message if there is no text in the PDF attribute ??

```
<?php $_pdf = $this->getProduct()->getPdf(); ?>
<?php if ($_pdf): ?>
    <h2><?php echo $this->__('PDF') ?></h2>
    <div class="std">
        <?php echo $this->helper('catalog/output')->productAttribute($this->getProduct(), $_pdf, 'pdf') ?>
    </div>

<?php endif; ?>
```

I know this is an easy question but i am new to magento and PHP so i am struggling to work this out.

Thank you in advance

Comment: if(empty($_pdf)) .... ;) gl hf

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably want to do something like this:

```
<?php $_pdf = $this->getProduct()->getPdf(); ?>
<?php if ($_pdf): ?>
    <h2><?php echo $this->__('PDF') ?></h2>
    <div class="std">
        <?php echo $this->helper('catalog/output')->productAttribute($this->getProduct(), $_pdf, 'pdf') ?>
    </div>
<?php else: ?>
    There's no PDF associated with this product!
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: i was writting "<?php else ?>". Now i see where i was going wrong. Thank you this should help in the future as well so thank you

Comment: never forget the colon :)! or use { } to start and end the block. <?php else: ?>